# How to soft delete many to many relations in TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that the records in my many to many relationship get soft deleted using type orm.

my models are something like this... (dumbed down example)

```
@Entity()
export class Book {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[]
}

@Entity()
export class Category {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string
}
```

These models are related in a join table named something like: `book_categories_category`.

I don't want the book to be soft deleted. I don't want the category to be soft deleted. I want the relation to be soft deleted. The goal is to maintain a history of which categories were once related to a book. My actual models are not book/category, so let's not get into how this doesn't make sense as a use case.

I've tried using the examples in typeorms documentation and reading through their github issues, but I can't figure out how to make the relation be the part that is soft deleted! Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution.. It's not great though. Going to post it here for anyone else searching, but won't accept for awhile to see if anyone has a better solution to offer up..

Something like this works, but isn't fun!

```
@Entity()
export class Book {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @OneToMany(() => BookCategory, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true
  })
  bookCategories: BookCategory[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinTable({
    ... set up table name and join column config here
  })
  categories: Category[]
}

@Entity()
export class BookCategory {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  bookId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  categoryId: number;

  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'bookId',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => Book, { primary: true })
  book: Book;

  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'categoryId',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => Category, { primary: true })
  category: Category;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
  deletedAt: Date;
}

@Entity()
export class Category {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string
}

// adding a category to a book
const book = repo.Find({id:1});

const existingCategory = book.categories.find(c => c.id === 1);

if (existingCategory) {
  existingCategory.deletedAt = null;
} else {
  book.categories.push(someCategory);
}

repo.save(book);

// similar for delete, but category.deletedAt = new Date();

// for reading

const builder = repo.createQueryBuilder('book')
.leftJoinAndSelect('book.bookCategories', 'category', 'category.deletedAt IS NULL')
.getMany()
```

I tried a lot of stuff, couldn't find a way to leverage the type orm soft delete features for many to many relations.. Kept getting errors about primary key columns being null or duplicated. Would love to see a cleaner solution, but for now this is where i'm at.